# Restful API optimization to get huge data

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I have a page for listing categories. There are parameters under categories and sub-parameters under parameters and data is huge.

Recently I developed and tested the same. It is taking a lot of time and the performance is severely hit. Because there are about 1600 API calls(API calls to fetch the data for each of the categories, parameters & sub-parameters) for that single page. I have two questions.

```
1) Which way is effective? a or b?

  a) I have an API to get data for a parameter, so that I can make use of this call 1600 times to get data for all categories/parameters/sub-parameters.

  b) Have one call to get all parameters/parameters/sub-parameters data

2) Does AWS charge based on number of the calls? For example, having one call to get data in one shot is cheaper than 1600 calls to get data for each of categories and parameters.
```

Comment: To answer your second question: I guess your using the api gateway? Then [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/api-gateway/pricing/) is the pricing sheet. You pay a fixed amount for 1 000 000 calls (in USA 3,50$) and you pay separate for the cache and the data transfer. So I guess you need to calculate yourself what would be cheaper for you.

Comment: @creyD so you mean to say it is advisable to reduce number of calls?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly AWS charges you on `CPU` active time, so basically whenever somebody calls the API, or any computation is being done on whatever you are hosting there.

For your other question I believe `A)` would be the better choice as it will reduce the load slightly (what I mean by this, is that there will be less computation but more frequently, which overall will speed up the whole process, since you will be splitting up the big data into smaller chunks) and will possibly not make a `traffic congestion` if many people are requesting at the same time.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on several factors. Overall *A* is probably the better option as the data transferred stays the same in both models. Therefore the load and processing power is very similar. In *A* you have the advantage of the spread of the risk (if one package get´s lost only few information gets lost) and probably better speed with the processor as it only needs to handle very small packages.

To answer your second question: I guess your using API Gateway? Here is [the pricing sheet](https://aws.amazon.com/de/api-gateway/pricing/). You pay a fixed amount for 1M calls (in USA 3,50$) and you pay separate for the cache and the data transfer. So I guess you need to calculate yourself what would be cheaper for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not using API gateway. It is an EC2 server.

Comment: Prices for this are [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)(If you are using the on demand payment model). According to this price sheet the incoming data transfer to the server is free. You are paying for the usage in hours. The question there is which model you are using. If you rather use a powerful CPU you can try to go with your model *B* and may save a little money and time if the connection and datatransfer are fast enough. If you use a very low CPU I guess *A* is still the way to go...